# ResetsPasswords trait not working as expected in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.6, laravel-5

I followed the instructions here

https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/how-to-make-user-login-and-registration-laravel-5-1/

for setting up login and registration.

Login and registration works correctly, but when I click on Forgot Password, I get the following exception :

> ErrorException in ResetsPasswords.php line 104: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController::showResetForm() must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in
>   ResetsPasswords.php on line 92 and defined

Not sure what is causing this since the request object seems to be getting passed in correctly

```
public function getReset($token = null)
{
    return $this->showResetForm($token);
}
```

I am running laravel 5.2.6

Comment: Post the code where you call `getReset`, `$token` seems to be null.

Comment: You have to use blade form instead of HTML form. You are not getting token in your controller right now.

Comment: @UmairHamid you dont have to use blade.

Comment: I misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 3):

If it says it needs 'an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request' then pass it one.

```
public function getReset(Request $request, $token = null)
{
   return $this->showResetForm($request, $token);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the laravel 5.2.6 tag there seems to be a bug in the ResetsPassword trait I had the some problem lookup the ResetsPassword.php on github and use the tag v5.2.6 and you will see that the Request is not passed to the showResetForm method you can fix this by manually adding it to the ResetsPassword trait but it would be better to just checkout laravel 5.2 in your composer file.

So in your composer.json it now probably looks like this for you.

```
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
```

But when you change it to

```
"laravel/framework": "5.2"
```

and run composer update

It should be fine atleast it worked for me. An alternative is to use the solution lagbox provided but then you have to change it manually on your server.

Comment: Good catch on that. I would just adjust it in your own controller, until the change is pushed with the next tagged release,

Comment: That is a solution too but you can also checkout the tag 5.2.5 because there  is only a token passed to the showResetForm only in 5.2.6 a Request is added to showResetForm but it is not added in getReset

Comment: There is a reason that versions get tagged. I would not mess with that, but you could as you have shown :).